# passing javascript parameters from an object constructor to the object's method?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, parameter-passing

Is it possible, while setting up a constructor, to have it's parameters passed right into one of it's methods? Here's what i mean:

```
function jedi(name,text){
    this.name = name;
    this.quote = function quote(name,text){
         return name + " said " + text;
    };
}

 var obiwan = new jedi('Obi-Wan','Fear leads to the darkside');
 console.log(obiwan.quote());  //renders as undefined said undefined

 //this works fine though
 console.log(obiwan.quote('Obi-Wan','Fear leads to the darkside'));
```

Is it possible to pass the 'name' and 'text' parameters right from 'var obiwan = new jedi()' to 'obiwan.quote()'? 
I hope my question makes sense. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me out!

Comment: Read up on `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the instance variables?

```
function jedi(name,text){
    this.name = name;
    this.text = text;

    this.quote = function quote(){
         return this.name + " said " + this.text;
    };
}

 var obiwan = new jedi('Obi-Wan','Fear leads to the darkside');
 console.log(obiwan.quote());  //works like a charm
```

Comment: OMG thank you. I knew i was missing something silly right in front of my face! Thank you Jari

Answer (score 0):

Give a different name to the parameters of `quote` function, than those given to the constructor parameters.

```
function jedi(name,text){
    this.name = name;
    this.quote = function quote(_name,_text){
         return (_name || name)  + " said " + (_text || text);
    };
}

var obiwan = new jedi('Obi-Wan','Fear leads to the darkside');

console.log(obiwan.quote());  
// would rendera as Obi-Wan said Fear leads to the darkside

console.log(obiwan.quote('I', "is the new X-men inspired from Assassin's Creed?"));
// would rendera as I said is the new X-men inspired from Assassin's Creed?
```